# storing values in multiple tables of a sqlite database based on radio button value

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

The two tables named adopter and donor are created in the database. When 'As a donor' radio button is clicked , the values of the registration form should be stored in donor table which is correctly working. The problem is when 'As a adopter' radio button is clicked , the values are stored in donor table and the id(primary key) is alone entered in adopter table. Here 'yes' radio button is 'As a donor' and 'no' radio button is 'As a adopter' I need your help.

```
    findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final String email = mail.getText().toString();
            final String name1 = name.getText().toString();
            final String pass = password.getText().toString();
            final String pass1 = password1.getText().toString();
            int id;
            id = student.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
            boolean check;
            check = stud.isChecked();
            if (!isValidName(name1)) {
                name.setError("Invalid name");
            }
            if (isValidName(name1) && !isValidEmail(email)) {
                mail.setError("Invalid Email");
            }
            if (isValidName(name1) && isValidEmail(email) && !isValidPassword(pass)) {
                password.setError("Invalid password");
            }
            if (isValidName(name1) && isValidEmail(email) && isValidPassword(pass)) {

                if (!isValidPassword(pass1)) {
                    password1.setError("Invalid password");
                }
            }
            if (isValidPassword(pass) != isValidPassword(pass1)) {
                password1.setError("The given passwords does not match ");
            }

            if (isValidName(name1) && isValidEmail(email) && isValidPassword(pass) && isValidPassword(pass) == isValidPassword(pass1) && (id == -1)) {
                Toast toast;
                toast = makeText(Register.this, "Click any one of the option", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
            if (isValidName(name1) && isValidEmail(email) && isValidPassword(pass) && (id != -1) && isValidPassword(pass) == isValidPassword(pass1) && (check == false)) {
                Toast msg1;
                msg1 = makeText(Register.this, "You can not register without clicking this checkbox", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                msg1.show();
            }
            if (isValidName(name1) && isValidEmail(email) && isValidPassword(pass)  && isValidPassword(pass) == isValidPassword(pass1) && (check == true) && (yes.isEnabled()==true)) {
                Toast msg2;
                msg2 = makeText(Register.this, "Step 1 of registration is completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                msg2.show();
                    Intent launch;
                    launch = new Intent(Register.this, donor.class);
                    startActivity(launch);
                    donor_insert(view);

                if (isValidName(name1) && isValidEmail(email) && isValidPassword(pass) && isValidPassword(pass) == isValidPassword(pass1) && (check == true) && (no.isEnabled()==true)){
                    Toast msg3;
                    msg3 = makeText(Register.this, "Step 1 of registration is completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    msg3.show();
                    Intent adopter;
                    adopter = new Intent(Register.this, adopter.class);
                    startActivity(adopter);
                    adopter_insert(view);
                }

            }

        }
    });
}
private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^(?=.*[a-z]).(?=\\S+$).{4,}$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}
private boolean isValidName(String name) {
    String name1 = "^(?=.*[a-z]).{1,}$";
    Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(name1);
    Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(name);
    return matcher1.matches();
}

// validating password with retype password
private boolean isValidPassword(String pass) {
    if (pass != null && pass.length() > 6) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public void adopter_insert(View view) {
     UserInputs adopt = new UserInputs(name.getText().toString(), mail.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
    dbHandler.adopter_insert(adopt);
    name.setText("");
    mail.setText("");
    password.setText("");
}
public void donor_insert(View view) {
    UserInputs donate = new UserInputs(name.getText().toString(), mail.getText().toString(), password.getText().toString());
    dbHandler.donor_insert(donate);
    name.setText("");
    mail.setText("");
    password.setText("");
}
```

}

{
//Dbhandler.java

```
public DBhandler(Context context, String name,
                 SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, DBNAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String create_table = ("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + "("
            + COLUMN_ID1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_NAME
            + " TEXT," + COLUMN_MAIL + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_PASSWORD + " BLOB " + ")");
    db.execSQL(create_table);
    String create_table1 = ("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE1 + "("
            + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_NAME
            + " TEXT," + COLUMN_MAIL + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_PASSWORD + " BLOB " + ")");
    db.execSQL(create_table1);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE);
    onCreate(db);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE1);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void adopter_insert(UserInputs inputs) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, inputs.getName());
    values.put(COLUMN_MAIL, inputs.getMail());
    values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, inputs.getPass());
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE, null, values);
    db.close();
}
public void donor_insert(UserInputs inputs) {
    ContentValues values1 = new ContentValues();
    values1.put(COLUMN_NAME, inputs.getName());
    values1.put(COLUMN_MAIL, inputs.getMail());
    values1.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, inputs.getPass());
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.insert(TABLE1, null, values1);
    db.close();
}
```

}

}

Comment: You can see in your last if statement you missing on breaches, whenever your inserting code execute at that time first time will always execute your `doner_insert(view)` method after that your if your adopter is checked than your `adopet_insert(view)` method call. Check your last if statement and on breaches.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Could you please change the error part of program alone and send it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see in you last if condition you need to set like this because when your donor is checked then your first if will be executed and if your adopter is checked then your second if will be executed.i hope this will help you.

```
if (isValidName(name1) && isValidEmail(email) && isValidPassword(pass)  && isValidPassword(pass) == isValidPassword(pass1) && (check == true) && (yes.isEnabled()==true)) 
{
     Toast msg2;
     msg2 = makeText(Register.this, "Step 1 of registration is completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
     msg2.show();
     Intent launch;
     launch = new Intent(Register.this, donor.class);
     startActivity(launch);
     donor_insert(view);
}
if (isValidName(name1) && isValidEmail(email) && isValidPassword(pass) && isValidPassword(pass) == isValidPassword(pass1) && (check == true) && (no.isEnabled()==true))
{
     Toast msg3;
     msg3 = makeText(Register.this, "Step 1 of registration is completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
     msg3.show();
     Intent adopter;
     adopter = new Intent(Register.this, adopter.class);
     startActivity(adopter);
     adopter_insert(view);
}
```

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much for solving my issue.